# Updating xml using lxml

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

This is one part of my xml :

```
<subtests id="39845890" name="Signallexikon:" subTestValuation="INFO" timestamp="2019-05-10T14:51:31.207+02:00" type="NewSubtest">
<subTestItem label="label:" value="Signallexikon:"/>
<subTestItem label="actual-value:" value="-"/>
<subTestItem label="rated-value:" value=" "/>
<subTestItem label="dimension:" value="-"/>
<subTestItem label="comment:" value=" "/>
</subtests>
```

I want to update the `label="actual-value:"` with `value= "myValue"` . 
First I  searched for `subtests` tag and then updated its child element `subTestItem` :

```
tree = etree.parse('my.xml')
subtest = tree.xpath("//subtests[@name='Signallexikon:']")[0]
subtestItem = subtest.xpath(".//subTestItem[@label='actual-value:']")[0]
subtestItem.set("value", 'myValue')
```

The problem is there is no error while running the code but it doesnt update my xml as well. What am I missing here??

Comment: well. I forgot to add one line in end : tree.write('my.xml')

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, I believe:

```
data = """[your xml above]"""
import lxml.etree as etree
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
subtestItem = tree.find(".//subTestItem[@label='actual-value:']")
```

Status before:

```
print( 'Current value is:', subtestItem.get('value'))
```

Output:

```
Current value is: -
```

Substitute values:

```
subtestItem.set("value", 'myValue')
```

Check status after:

```
print('Current value is:', subtestItem.get('value'))
```

Output:

```
Current value is: myValue
```

And just to be on the safe side, check again:

```
print(etree.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Output:

```
<subtests id="39845890" name="Signallexikon:" subTestValuation="INFO" timestamp="2019-05-10T14:51:31.207+02:00" type="NewSubtest">
<subTestItem label="label:" value="Signallexikon:"/>
<subTestItem label="actual-value:" value="myValue"/>
<subTestItem label="rated-value:" value=" "/>
<subTestItem label="dimension:" value="-"/>
<subTestItem label="comment:" value=" "/>
</subtests>
```